# How to add input file plain text and submit to publish?

Tags: jquery, theme-customizer

Update: *I got it to update the database and allow the submit but it only saves the local directory path and file name, but it should be saving the file contents, not the path and file name.*

It is simple, I want the browse button to be exactly like the normal customizer text box and save normally just like the text box into database.

Here is the code I have so far,

`<input class="file" type="file" name="file" value="<?php echo esc_attr($this->value()); ?>" accept="text/plain">`

I am trying to add a `<input type="file" ... >` to wordpress custom control for customizer. I have it displaying the browse button but when you select a file it does not register as being modified and that means it does not change the publish button to allow the submit. I need the file to be read as plain text exactly like a regular text box but using the browse button and selecting the text file. I do not want the file to be uploaded to the upload directory only read exactly the same as a text box. I assume I need a jquery or something to fix this to make the selection allow the submit?

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: For what? The Input line?

Comment: It is simple, I want the browse button to be exactly like the normal text box and save normally just like the text box into database.

Comment: What's the code you're using the add the control to the Customizer?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Any spesific questions if you do not understand the question?

Comment: I know the browse button is not normally used but it should function fine with the correct type of code. Any ideas?